# How do you iterate and keep the top 10 max? Python

Tags: python

I have a list of numbers that needs to be calculated from a function. And i need to calculate 2 millions times. I could have done it this way but is there a simpler way:

```
def funcx(): 
  return random.random() # for simplicity we use random

top10 = [] # max len = 10
for i in range(2000000):
  j = funcx()
  top10.append(j)
  top10 = sorted(top10, reverse=True)[:10]
```

Comment: This is a comfortable way of doing it. However, I would consider implementing insertion sort and check if your new value is bigger than the max value of the list [the first or last item] and see if you got to sort it again. This should be efficient considering there are only 10 items :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: 2013-me was confused, at best, and this is not correct. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68587827/1126841 instead.

---

<strike>Use a fixed-size heap instead of sorting the list each time:</strike>

```
import heapq
top10=[]
for i in range(2000000):
    heapq.heappush(top10, funcx())
    top10 = top10[:10]
```

Asymptotically, the running time is the same, but there should be less overhead.

Another option is to use the `nsmallest` function:

```
heapq.nsmallest(10, (funcx() for i in range(2000000)) )
```

This is less efficient than simply sorting the list and return the first 10 items, but it should (i.e., I didn't check) use less memory.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `heapq.heappush(top10, funcx())`?

Comment: Yeah, I was treating `heappush` as a method for a heap referenced by `heapq`, rather than a function in the `heapq` module that takes a list-as-heap as an argument.

Comment: The first code block is wrong and it won't give top 10!! For example let's take simplified version with top 3 elements: `top = [1, 3, 4]` then perform `heapq.heappush(top, 2)` which leaves you with `top == [1, 2, 4]` which aren't 3 smallest elements. You would need to repeatedly perform heappop in order to make this work which is quite inefficient. I tried to post answer with fixed version.

Comment: Ugh, you're right. Not sure what I was thinking back then.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to show correct solution using fixed size heap ([accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17527689/6604502) is incorrect).
Let's say you want 10 smallest elements. Then you can use max heap and after each push perform a pop. The pop will remove the largest element leaving you with array of 10 smallest elements. There is even and efficient operation `heapq.heappushpop`. The code for 10 smallest elements then look like:

```
import heapq
top10 = []
for i in range(2000000):
    # Heapq implements min heap, so we need to negate the numbers
    heapq.heappushpop(top10, -funcx())
print(top10)
```

Anyways this code is basically the same as implementation of `heapq.nsmallest` (it handles some extra corner cases e.g. `n == 1`), so you better use that:

```py
heapq.nsmallest(10, (funcx() for i in range(2000000)))
```

or `heap.nlargest` of n largest elements.

Answer (score -1):

As another user pointed out, I would also recommend implementing insertion sort. However, as you currently have it. You can simply look for the max value and remove it from the list, and repeat 10 times.

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> max(x)
5
>>> x.remove(5)
>>> max(x)
4
```